# Where is my remote git repository password stored on the local machine?

Tags: git, credentials, credential-manager

I have a git repository set up on bitbucket

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/my_repository_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/my_repository_name.git (push)
```

I pull and push to the repository from my office workstation and home PC.
When I push or pull from my office workstation, it prompts me for the password.
However when I push or pull from my home PC it doesn't prompt for a password.

I don't specifically remember what I did on my home PC to remember the password.

running `$ git config credential.helper` returns `manager`

```
$ git config credential.helper
manager
```

Contents `.gitconfig` file in my user folder at root level

```
[user]
name = myusername
email = user.name@email.com
```

Where is the password stored on the local disk?

What is the command to check the status of current credentials?

How do I similarly remember the password on my office workstation?

Note: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Have you checked this https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html

Comment: @Smit I haven't used any of the methods given there

Comment: Are you using the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) at both home and work? If you are at work, it should remember. (link has information about where passwords are stored).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

if `$ git config credential.helper` returns `manager`, the password is stored in the windows credential manager, if it returns `store`, password is stored in a `.git-credentials` file in the user folder.

Comment: It can be `osxkeychain` in that case then it is stored in keychain (Mac)

Comment: What if it returns helper-selector?

Answer (score 23):

With the default configuration of git on windows, this is stored in Windows under: `control panel` => `User` => `Credential manager`.

[See a more details answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437252/717372)

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo cat ~/.git-credentials
```

If you have saved credentials locally, will yield
`https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD_OR_TOKEN_IN_USE>@github.com`

Answer (score 3):

In my case `git config credential.helper` was empty (local and global both). Turns out the credentials were stored in KWallet. Those are found in KWalletManager under ksshaskpass (even though I am using HTTPS auth for this particular repo) under "Passwords".

Comment: I was also looking in KWallet, but the `ksshaskpass` name seemed unrelated so I missed it. Thanks for pointing this!