# Git Extensions stored wrong credentials

Tags: git, git-extensions

My username and password were stored somewhere in internals of Git Extensions. After some time it was necessary to give username and password again and I gave wrong pass many times.

Now if I want to pull something etc. I receive `fatal: Authentication failed`. I cannot give new password, it seems to be stored and I don't know how to change it.

Is it possible to delete the old credentials?

I have 2.51.04 version. I have uninstalled it and install again and it doesnt help me.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

GitExtensions doesn't store any passwords.

They are stored by git or, more exactly, by "git credential manager" that stores them inside windows.

Search for [Credential manager](https://support.microsoft.com/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)* in the start menu and you should find it. Otherwise, it should be in: `Control panel` => `User Accounts` => `Credential manager`

Then select the tab `Windows credential` and you will see keys named like `git:xxxx`.

Detailed steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/717372) or in [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)

`*`: what to look for on system in other languages:

- In french, "Gestionnaire d’informations d’identification"
- In German, "Netzwerkkennwörter verwalten"

Comment: credential manage is not found in the start menu

Comment: which version of windows? It's in the "Control panel"...

Comment: I have found it. Thanks. It was Windows 7, but other localization :)

Comment: How is the entry called in *Credentials Manager* under *Generic*? There is no GIT entry ...

Comment: @testing I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks that was to the point and quick!

Comment: Thanks man! On Windows 10 worked well!

Comment: In German: "Netzwerkkennwörter verwalten"

Comment: @Philippe  for Windows 10 it's under:
`Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`