# Need to share Local Git Repo without remote - Remove all credentials

Tags: git

So I couldn't find similar questions.

I need to share a local git repo with all local branches, stashes, labels, and so on, without actually pushing to my organization's remote, since I do not have access.
To do this, I was planning to upload the zip of the local repo in an email, which they later can push to an official remote.
How can I remove all my credentials from the `.git` directory? Like my name, email and so on. Like I am fine for it to show in the history. I just don't want it show automatically later on. Also, are any passwords stored in the `.git` folder?

Comment: Edit the .git/config file

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42595596/5784831. Why do you want to remove your name or email?

Comment: @Christoph Because I want to send it via email to my coworkers so that they can push it to remote after I've left. But they can still locally use it with my credentials. So I would like to clear them all.

Comment: But they can do that - they can any remote they like.